# Как скопировать текст из одного RichTextBox в другой?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как правильно скопировать текст из одного RichTextBox в другой с сохранением цветов и шрифта текста?

Comment: что то типа **assign**  линк по теме [Assign in c# (как в Delphi)][1]


  [1]: http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/2/43703/

Answer (score 1):

Использовать свойство [RichTextBox.Rtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx)